# Using firebase cli when not installed globally

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I'm using my work computer while developing a sort of side project. Nothing crazy just learning some new firebase stuff. Anyways, because it is a work computer I can't install modules globally. So when it came to installing firebase-cli I tried using the recommended global command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

That didn't work because I don't have permission due to this being a work computer. So I created a firebase folder just for this project and ran

```
npm install firebase-tools
```

In the new folder. Once finished I tried running

```
firebase -version
```

But this resulted in

```
firebase: command not found
```

I thought this would work since I'm in the directory I created and installed firebase in but it doesn't work. Any help please!

Comment: Did you try installing the standalone binary? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-standalone-binary

Comment: I just tried it and that seems to have worked. thatnks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run any command from a package that was installed in a project, use [`npm exec`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-exec) from the project folder.

```
npm exec -- firebase [CLI args]
```

The version command you were trying to run would go like this (note it's two dashes for the flag)

```
npm exec -- firebase --version
```